# Footer at bottom but not Fixed

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page, and I am facing nightmares because of the footer: I have used CCS tricks to make the footer always visible at the bottom and it works perfectly but my background image, which is set to `size:cover` is not working.

Comment: please share some of your code

Comment: Dear friend.
Please do not share your code in the comment.
You can easily edit your post 
and place the html and css code of your question

Comment: thanks brother this is my frist time i m using stack overflow (Using) but used a reference many time.

Comment: Please share your html and css code

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
background-size: cover;